# Avoiding $watch to fire at instantiation of controller

Tags: angularjs

I have this controller:

```
  .controller('MasterAdminUserIdCtrl', function ($scope, user) {
    $scope.user = user;
    $scope.userWasEdited = false;


    $scope.$watch('user', function(){
      $scope.userWasEdited = true
    }, true);
```

I want to check if the user has changed any of the data of the user, so I have a watch on it. Problem is the watch always fires when the controller is instantiated. What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: Why do you need a watch instead of just working with data bindings?

Comment: I want to give the user a warning if he has unsaved changes and trying to leave the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that something was changed:

```
$scope.$watch('user', f, true);
function f(newValue, oldValue){
    // here you can add some conditions using oldValue & newValue. E.g:
    if ( oldValue !== newValue ) {
        $scope.userWasEdited = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If there's not a lot of data in my model I like to store a copy and set up a watch to update the flag by comparing the new values to the old.  This lets the user undo or change values back original and not have to see the warning that there are unsaved changes.

I store an `angular.copy()` of the model in lastModel when I get it from the server or save it to the server and set up a watch that executes the compare function each digest cycle and calls the second function when the value has changed to set the `isChanged` flag:

```
$scope.model = Model;
$scope.lastModel = angular.copy($scope.model);
$scope.$watch(function () {
    currentJSON = angular.toJson($scope.model);
    lastJSON = angular.toJson($scope.lastModel);
    var changed = currentJSON != lastJSON;
    return changed;
}, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.isChanged = newValue;
});
```

This way I don't have to watch for each individual change and it is 100% going to catch any changes made to the model that I would post back to the server.

I just tested the speed `angular.toJson()` on one page and a model with a fairly simple object and three arrays with 100 total objects in them produces 9.5kb of JSON in about 0.35ms.  So 0.70 ms for two means you could probably have a model with over 2000 objects and still have it take less than 1/60th a second, at least on a computer.  If you were watching for individual changes on all those values I imagine that would take even more time since angular really does something similar each cycle to look for changes.